# Cant Add Entity Framework and System.Web.dll in the same Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll, .net-standard

I have the following Problem. I try to write a Class Library for my ASP.NET MVC 5 Project.

So I want to add the NuGet Package for the Entity Framework 6.2.0 and the System.Web.dll.

My Class Library has the Property:

Target framework: .NET Standard 2.0

My ASP.NET MVC Project have:

.NET Framework 4.6.1

So when I try to add the System.Web.dll I become the following error:

[image]

When I change the Target framework in my Library to .NET Standard 1.6 I can add the System.Web.dll but I become the Error:

[image]

I asked Google for the .NET Standards and found this Table

[image]

So I think .NET Standard 2.0 work with 4.6.1. And in my ASP.NET MVC Project I can add Entity Framework 6.2.0 and System.Web.dll so why I cant do this for my Class Library?

P.S. I only see .NET Standards in the porperty window.

[image]

Comment: EF6.x does not support ".NET Standard"-only environments, that's why it's breaking. Unless you *need* to target non-Windows platforms you should switch back to ".NET Framework" instead of ".NET Standard".

Comment: @Dai and how I swith back to .NET Famework?. In the property window i have only a list of .NET Standards no .NET Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So i think .NET Standard 2.0 work with 4.6.1.

A .NET Standard 2.0 library **can be consumed by** a .NET Framework 4.6.1 library.

<s>However, a .NET Standard 2.0 library **cannot reference** a .NET Framework library, such as `System.Web`.</s> It is possible for a .NET Standard 2.0 library to reference a .NET Framework library, but [only in compatibility mode](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/347/upgrading-asp-net-libraries-to-net-standard). It is recommended to use compatibility mode **only for cases where a .NET Standard option is not yet available**. Since we know that `System.Web` (and many other .NET Framework namespaces) will never be released on .NET Standard, you should not reference it from a .NET Standard library.

.NET Standard is for **portable libraries** that need to run on multiple platforms (such as .NET Framework and .NET Core). If this is simply an application layer that will never be used outside of your application, you should have the same target as your ASP.NET MVC Project (`.NET Framework 4.6.1`).

You can switch by manually changing the target in the `.csproj` file.

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

1. Right-click on your project node in Solution Explorer and click `Unload Project`.
2. Right-click the project node again and click `Edit <projectName>.csproj`.

Comment: thanks for you anwser. I have add a screenshot to my post. In the property window i dont have .NET Framework to select only .NET Standard?

Comment: i dont have a .csproj file in my Clas Library Project?